# C++ (ATL) ITypeInfo.GetContainingTypeLib fails when passed live instance of VBA Class

Tags: c++, excel, vba, com, typeinfo

So I asked this question in a C# context and I have [set bounty over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912746/c-sharp-itypeinfo-getcontainingtypelib-fails-when-passed-live-instance-of-vba-cl).

I have written an equivalent fragment of C++ code (to be housed within an ATL DLL project) to tap C++ developers experience as well.

IDispatch has a method called GetTypeInfo() with which one can acquire a pointer to ITypeInfo.  ITypeInfo itself has a method called GetContainingTypeLib which gets the containing ITypeLib (as it says).  This is useful when given a CoClass instance once can get to all the other CoClasses in a given DLL, very useful for reflection.

I had wondered if Excel VBA would co-operate in a similar fashion and return a ITypeLib for the containing VBA project and equally allow me to iterate over all the types found therein.  So I wrote some test C# code and that is linked.  Here I give equivalent C++ code to tap C++ experience.

The IDL...

```
[
    object,
    uuid(ddc4e135-49d6-49f8-ad57-ded4180095fd),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ICoClassGetContainingTypeLib : IDispatch
{
    HRESULT GetContainingTypeLib(IDispatch* vbaClass, IUnknown** iunkTypeLib);
};

[
    uuid(bc8410a6-802a-4f91-a73b-c03179bb402b)
]
coclass CoClassGetContainingTypeLib
{
    [default] interface ICoClassGetContainingTypeLib;
};
```

The cpp method implementation

```
STDMETHODIMP CCoClassGetContainingTypeLib::GetContainingTypeLib(IDispatch* vbaClass, IUnknown** iunkTypeLib)
{
    CComPtr<IDispatch> itfDispatch(vbaClass);
    CComPtr<ITypeInfo> pITypeInfo;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    HRESULT hr2 = S_OK;
    try
    {

        hr = itfDispatch->GetTypeInfo(0, 0, &pITypeInfo);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
        {
            UINT* idx(0);
            CComQIPtr<ITypeLib> pTLib;
            HRESULT hr2 = pITypeInfo->GetContainingTypeLib(&pTLib, idx);
            return hr2; // throws exception Exception 0x800A88C1 
            // which ends u[p at 35009

            //TODO If successful copy to ByRef param  iunkTypeLib
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

And the header declaration

```
STDMETHOD(GetContainingTypeLib)(IDispatch* vbaClass, IUnknown** iunkTypeLib);
```

And some client VBA

```
Sub TestGetContainingTypeLib()

    Dim oTR As ToolsReferences  '* could be ANY VBA class
    Set oTR = New ToolsReferences   '* could be ANY VBA class

    '* instantiate my ATL project
    Dim oTest As GetContainingTypeLibTestLib.CoClassGetContainingTypeLib
    Set oTest = New GetContainingTypeLibTestLib.CoClassGetContainingTypeLib

    Dim iunkTypeLib As IUnknown
    Set iunkTypeLib = Nothing   '* not strictly required
    Call oTest.GetContainingTypeLib(oTR, iunkTypeLib)

End Sub
```

There is very little on the Internet to explain the exception number of 0x800A88C1 .  I think this the Excel team saying no.

Comment: It's normal when the type info is not loaded from a statically compiled type library, but instead synthesized on the fly. Which is the case for languages like VBA or JavaScript, where objects are built entirely at runtime.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : I kind of agree but VBA does go through a compilation step.

Comment: Sure, that is Excel saying "no!".  The docs are not great, they talk about an "ITypeLib server".  A bit over the top, in practice you need code that know hows to load a type library and hands out the info from it to other code.  Excel actually has one, but it is only active in the VBA code editor.  A ball that gets rolling under the hood with LoadTypeLib().  It disappears at runtime, the type library plays no role anymore when the compiled VBA code already knows what guids to use.  LoadTypeLib() is chicken-and-egg, extra squirrily in VBA with the compiler auto-generating .oca files.

Comment: @HansPassant I am so glad you have responded, you are a great expert ... I have code to loop through the types thanks.  I think I agree with you that Excel does this, for when a workbook references another workbook how else does the Intellisense operate.  It's a shame if, as you say, that it disappears at run-time.  What is .oca files please?

Comment: This depth of discussion for vba is vital so I hope some form of answer incorporating what is discussed is formed so we have the benefit of being able to easily find and view it in future. +1